# On the tube or in the tube?

Tags: grammar

The directions for use and warnings are printed *on* the tube or *in* the tube?

Which one, *on* or *in* is correct?

Comment: It depends where the directions and warnings actually are. I'd take _on_ to mean 'on the outside of' and _in_ to mean "inside of".

Answer (score 3):

You haven't told us what precisely you mean by "the tube". Here is an example:

[image]

You can see that, if you wrote instructions in (inside) this particular tube, no-one would be able to read them.